# Having some problems with side by side divs and their heights

Tags: html, css

If the content inside the left div increases the height of the overall layout will increase accordingly and everything will work as it should: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTTpc/2/). However if the content inside the right div increases in height, the layout doesn't increase with it: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTTpc/1/)

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="contain">
        <div class="one">
       </div><div class="two">
                 <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
   display: block;
   width: 500px;
   min-height: 500px;
   background-color: black;    
   border: 2px solid black;
}

.contain {
   display: block;
   width: 500px;
   min-height: 500px;
   background: red;
}

.one {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    bottom:200px;
}

.two {
    float:right;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: purple;

}

.bottom {
    display:block;
    background: blue;
    width: 500px;
    height:200px;  
    bottom: 0;    
}
```

​Would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from your code that you want the two boxes (one and two) to be bottom aligned if they don't fill the space? If so, you should try this:

```
.one {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.two {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: purple;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

You are making both a set width, so set both as `inline-block` and they should sit side-by-side, and both take up space. Floated blocks do not take up space.

Comment: Actually I needed them to be aligned to the top, so I changed `bottom` to `top` and it seems to be working fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add font-size:0 to class="contain" as it has inline-block divs inside it which by their nature taking the empty whitespace in markup and creates gaps.
If needed, add font-size property in inner elements separately.